# Jest how to mock implementation of an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

as stated in the title I'm trying to mock the implementation of one function. I'm new to testing React apps. I've been looking for hours on the internet on how to achieve my goal so let me explain.

I've already moved the API call to a different file (/utils/fetchGetCard.js):

```
export const fetchGetCard = (lang, word) => {
    return fetch("/getCard", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ lang: lang, word: word })
    }).then(response => response.text())
}
```

Then I have a functional component in SearchCard.jsx:

```
    const searchCard = (event) => {

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        if (event.currentTarget.checkValidity() === true) {
            setValidated(false);
            fetchGetCard(selectInput.current.value, wordInput.current.value)
                .then(data => {
                    if (data === "ERR") {
                        console.log("Oops, something went wrong!");
                    } else if (data === "MISSING_WORD") {
                        console.log("Somehow your word wasn't passed to the backend");
                    } else {
                        if (data === '') {
                            showModal(wordInput.current.value);
                        } else {
                            setCardInfo(JSON.parse(data));
                            setCardLang(selectInput.current.value);
                            setFound(true);
                        }
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                })
        } else {
            setValidated(true);
        }
    }
```

The searchCard function is tied to Form component's onSubmit (from react-bootstrap).
Now I want to make a test in which I'd render the component, then type some info and press the button. In this part I'd probably want to mock the API call to return a correct hardcoded data. Finally, I'd like to check if the new component (based on the API data) is rendered. This is what I have so far:

```
import SearchCard from './SearchCard.jsx';
import { render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { fireEvent, screen } from "@testing-library/dom";
import { fetchGetCard } from "../utils/fetchGetCard.js";

jest.mock("../utils/fetchGetCard.js");

test("render SearchCard when card has been found", async () => {

    fetchGetCard.mockImplementation(() => {
        `{
            "word": "hund",
            "pronounciation": "ˈhʉn",
            "translation": [
                {
                    "type": "noun",
                    "meaning": "Its a dog mkay?",
                    "grammarNoun": {
                        "countable": "true",
                        "gender": "masculine",
                        "singularIndefinite": "en hund",
                        "singularDefinite": "hunden",
                        "pluralIndefinite": "hunder",
                        "pluralDefinite": "hundene"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }`
    });

    render(<SearchCard />);
    const testWordInput = screen.getByTestId("testWordInput");
    testWordInput.innerHTML = "hund";
    const testButtonSearch = screen.getByTestId("testButtonSearch");
    fireEvent.click(testButtonSearch);

    expect(fetchGetCard).toHaveBeenCalled();

    await waitFor(() => screen.findByTestId("testFoundCard"));

    expect(screen.getByText("hʉn")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Any guidance will be really appreciated!

**EDIT 1:**
Changing testWordInput.innerHTML to testWordInput.value fixed it, and it seems that I have successfully mocked the fetchGetCard function. It seems though, that setCardInfo(), setCardLang() and setFound() (possibly all setters) aren't working. These methods are from useState hook. Should they work just fine or is there something I can do to change state?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem: as stated in the edit I managed to get the correct result from `expect(fetchGetCard).toHaveBeenCalled()`. The last thing was my bad and I actually haven't assigned the "testFoundCard" id to anything in the DOM and I ended up with:

`await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText("hundene")).toBeInTheDocument());`

Now it works!